# iOS 7 blur effect on videoPlayer

Tags: ios7, blur, video-player

I want to make blur effect on video player.
So I play video using AVPlayer and whenever I want to share the video to social, share window display on video player. just I want to apply blur effect to share window's background.

renderContext function doesn't render AVPlayer's layer. But I saw that apple's new API drawViewHierarchyInRect will render specific layers such as video player or OpenGL layer.

So I used drawViewHierarchyInRect and it works as well on simulator but not on device.

Any idea?

```
- (UIImage *)snapshotOfVideoPlayer
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, 1.0);
    [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: Which device is it? Does the blur effect/animation stopped (for efficiencies)?

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Device is iPad4 with iOS 7. It does't work at all. Always black image.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way is using the AVAssetImageGenerator.
Assuming you have a reference to your AVPlayerItem:

```
AVURLAsset *asset = (AVURLAsset *)self.playerItem.asset;
AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
CGImageRef thumb = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:self.playerItem.currentTime
                                                  actualTime:NULL
                                                       error:NULL];
self.videoScreenshotIV.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:thumb];
```

1. Notice the self.playerItem.currentTime. This will ensure the image will be exactly the same as the moment of the screenshot.
2. The videoScreenshotIV is an UIImageView (contentMode scaleAspectFit) that is directly over the avplayer view with exactly the same bounds. I hide this UIImageView until I need to take a screenshot, I then first unhide it and set the image, then take the screenshot and then hide it again. It works perfectly! :)